# convert java static to swift code

Tags: java, swift, struct, static

Hi im lost of how to convert this piece of code to Swift.
Can someone help me out?

```
Class Break {
    public static abstract class BreakType extends Enum{ 
         Static { 
              COFFEE = new BreakType("COFFEE",0){
                 public int getmin(){
                      return 10;
                 }
                 public boolean isPayed(){
                      return true;
                 }
              };
         }
    }
    public static list getBreaks(Double d, Double d1){
        //CODE
    }
}
```

i thought `struct` was the way to go but i didn't quite see how.

Any help or pointing in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should avoid questions like "Do it for me". But I'm felling generous so here is the translation for you:

```
class Break {
  enum BreakType {
    case Coffee

    func getMin() -> Int {
      return 10
    }
    func isPayed() -> Bool {
      return true
    }
  }

  static func getBreaks(d:Double, d1:Double) -> [AnyObject] {
    //CODE
    return []
  }
}
```

You can call `getMin` or `isPlayed` like so `BreakType.Coffee.getMin()`

Comment: Thank you! i was only asking for the right direction, you giving me code was certainly not the way i wanted to go, even though after reading the question again, may seemed like it. Im sorry. But thank you very much for helping me out! i appreciate it